# Does UI-Router require module names that look like the route names?

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui

The FAQ's for ui-router says this:

> With #492 merged (v0.2.8), you can now register states in any order and across modules. You can register children before the parent state exists. It will queue them up and once the parent state is registered then the child will be registered. Note: You still need to manage module dependencies.

```
angular.module('main', ['main.page1']).config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main', {...})
});

angular.module('main.page1', []).config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main.page1', {...})
});
```

The quoted text does not explicitly state that the naming of the modules is significant to the success of the routing states configuration. It seems to say that no matter where your routing states are defined, as long as the modules are all considered 'properly dependent' then all the configured states will be registered, put in order, and become operational.

However, in the example that follows immediately after that text above, the naming of the related modules follows the naming of the routes precisely. This is also true in the following example which is included in the ui-router repo that can be downloaded from github.

```
angular.module('uiRouterSample', [
  'uiRouterSample.contacts',
  'uiRouterSample.contacts.service',
  'uiRouterSample.utils.service',
  'ui.router', 
  'ngAnimate'
])

angular.module('uiRouterSample.contacts', [
  'ui.router'
])
```

I was under the impression that 'managing module dependencies' required creating a tree of dependent modules that were referenced by their named list of requested dependencies to be injected. However, the implication of the examples is that (at least ui-router) depends on a module naming hierarchy as well as a state naming hierarchy.

And in fact, I'm having trouble navigating between states configured in the config functions of different modules. So if there is some guidance about 'managing module dependencies' that will make the promise true that 'now you can register states in any order and from any module', then I would like to be let in on the secret.

If the naming is not significant, then could someone make explicit just exactly which direction the dependencies in the modules have to point in order for ui-router states to see their sub-states?

In the dependencies among the modules themselves, the most-shared dependencies are near the root, because the branching that occurs as we travel toward the leaves limits cross-branch dependencies because of the likelihood of circular referencing. So I'm expecting to hear that ui-router also sees states that are farther from the root as child states, and that they have to be siblings in case we want to traverse in any direction but up and down, (from parent to children)

But again, my question is about the naming hierarchy: must the state hierarchy and the module hierarchy be identically named (unlikely), or must the dependency hierarchy for states and modules be semantically identical, or, more likely, must they be traversable identically? Or does Angular throw everything into a big pot and let the components just dig in?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> Or does Angular throw everything into a big pot and let the components just dig in?

To be short it does :) Check the following Plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/IYDLbkF11nwCj43wR3jK?p=preview

1. Load `b.js`, contains module `bar`.
2. Module `bar` sets up state `charlie`, child of `alpha`
3. Load `a.js`, contains module `foo` injects `bar`.
4. Module `foo` sets up state `bravo`, child of state `alpha`
5. Module `foo` sets up state `alpha`

And it "Just works™" They keep the names sane in the examples so it doesn't get confusing like the above here. I'de say it's best practive to do so. Otherwise you're going to have a hell of a time keeping track of what is what.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read through my question. And the plnkr is very clear. Confirmation is better than consternation. My appreciation is large.

Comment: Messed with the voting to see what the behavior was. It was not about the correctness or the value of the answer.

Comment: I had to remove the checkmark to maybe get your attention again.

Comment: I'm sorry?! :) I was assuming the answer was ok and you we're happy with it. What's the problem?

Comment: I had to remove the checkmark to maybe get your attention again. Commenting out the 'bar' in 'foo' and putting 'foo' in 'bar' causes all the angular stuff relating to 'bar' to stop working. So its not just one big pot exactly. Bi-directional references for bar in foo and foo in bar works in this case. But I think the module references have to be a simple b-tree and the states have to follow the identical pattern of links and directionality. Si o no?

Comment: I see what you mean. Did some testing but didn't try that :( I think you're right, got to do some testing to figure out what's actually going on and be sure but i'm very low on time at the moment. Will get back at this when i've got some time. Nice find tho.